# battery capacity indicator button not working

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

i have this button (battery capacity indicator) in my macbook pro 2011 series that shows battery capacity, but when i press it nothing happens.

can i know if it is plugged in or not via a terminal command?

`e.g.: ubuntu have 'lspci' command to know the plugged in devices`

or how can i know if it is plugged via hardware disassembly ?

## Edit:

here is how the button look like, its on the left of the macbook

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Where is this button located?

Comment: its on the left of the macbook, i've edit the post with an image of the button

Comment: What's wrong with OS X's menu bar icon?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it, but i wanna check the battery even when the laptop is turned off

Comment: Has the MacBook ever been opened? It could be possible that the cable connecting it is loose/disconnected. Also, have you tried resetting the SMC as per [here](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295)?

Comment: I am not sure what is your question here. The indicator seems broken. Now you search for a terminal command that works when the Mac is turned off?

Comment: @NetherLinks yea i've opened it before, but it was not working before i opened it

Comment: @AbdallahSamman Okay, you should still attempt to reset the SMC, as the article indicates it controls the battery indicator lights.

Comment: @n1000 i am searching for a command to check if this button thing chipset is known for the mac or not, is that possible? "lspci" in ubuntu shows all chipsets in the device as in this pic http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-w9DRLXJ2XFo/T_CSmHQw7BI/AAAAAAAAAFQ/KAOsBknNySU/s1600/lspci.png , is there something similar for mac os so i can check this battery capacity indicator chipset is shown there or not

Comment: I see. Maybe you should make your question a bit more precise then.

Comment: @NetherLinks i just reset the smc, unfortunately its still not doing anything when i press it

Comment: I would recommend opening it again and to carefully and thoroughly verify that the cable running from the indicator to the mainboard is indeed properly attached. If it is, your best bet will be to order a replacement part from an Apple Authorized partner or just let them handle the repair.

Comment: That is your only indicator of battery life? Or you mean just when it is closed? You don't have the bar on top that shows battery? What about just getting a battery indicator application like Battery Operator. I know this doesn't solve your broken hard wired indicator, but it will tell you how much battery you have left, and indicate when it's charging.

Answer (score 3):

Your indicator light seems broken and is pretty much hardwired. Did it ever see any moisture? Replacing it is a relatively difficult procedure, as seen in this [video](https://youtu.be/UYi9NhyASLg). You will find more guides on iFixit (e.g. [this one](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Late+2008+and+Early+2009+Battery+Connector+Replacement/827)) explaining how to get to the Battery Indicator Light. But I don't know where you could get a new one if yours is broken.

If you are looking for a terminal command to get your current power status, use [pmset](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html). `pmset -g batt` will tell your the current power source and remaining battery capacity:

```
$ pmset -g batt

Now drawing from 'AC Power'
 -InternalBattery-0 99%; charged; 0:00 remaining
```

Comment: i already can see the battery in the menu bar, i just want this button to work

Comment: Then you will probably have to bring it to the Apple store... Since the indicator is hardwired there is not much you can do.

Comment: there is no apple store in my country (lebanon), do you know something else i can do, i am a bit good at hardware, if i know where is the wire so i can check if its plugged in or not it will be great

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: i saw the video and saw where is the wire,tried unplugging it and replugging it, did not work. now i know its not working at all.

Comment: At least you know for sure now...

Answer (score 1):

I would personally recommend a [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201295).

The SMC (System Management Controller) is involved in controlling peripherals such as LEDs, fans, touch pads, keyboards etc, and resetting it can often solve many related problems.

To reset the SMC, reboot the MacBook, and when the apple chime noise sounds and the screen is at blank white state. Press and hold the buttons `Shift`, `Control` and `Option`, release these 3 buttons simultaneously after a few seconds to successfully reset the SMC.

For More information: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/reset-macs-smc-pram/

Of course there is always the possibility that this is a hardware problem. If this is the case, then (according [to this blog](http://www.engadget.com/question/how-to-fix-my-broken-battery-light-indicator-ewa/)) this small black cable has either come loose or is damaged; a problem which can be rectified by the nearest apple store, and they will likely do it for free.

[image]

Hope this has helped, and interested to know if the SMC reset worked out.

Comment: you did not read the comments before you posting this, i've tried smc reset already but it didn't work, i believe it is a hardware issue

Comment: Quite right i did not read them, my bad. Either way interesting to know that the SMC was ineffectual, if it's the hardware then it could be a myriad of problems, the most like being mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a MacBook Pro whose battery capacity indicator button was not working very well. I had to press the button quite hard to get any indication from the LEDs. Have you tried pressing the button hard, maybe using a fingernail to help?

With mine, if I pressed it at the right angle, and pressed quite deeply, it would sometimes work.

(I wish the current model MacBook Pro still had that indicator, it's very useful to know the battery charge without opening the computer.)

Comment: tried pressing it as hard as i can, no signs of life ... thanks anyway

Comment: Well, it was worth a try …

Answer (score 0):

Every battery in a MacBook has a battery processor, which, from time to time, should be recalibrated. Like this:

1. Fully charge your Mac
2. Use it until the battery dies
3. Once dead, wait at least 5 hours, no less, then plug it in and charge it to 100%, **without using it**.

The battery percentage reading on your Mac should now be more accurate.

If this doesn't fix it, I'd say that the battery indicator part has gone out. I'd go to iFixit.com for a repair guide and check eBay for parts.

Comment: will try this today and tell you what happens