# Is there a battery monitoring app that can send a notification when the battery reaches X %?

Tags: iphone, applications

I would especially love an app where you could customize the percentage at which point the app will send a notification (for example, 80%). I looked at some battery apps I found on AppStore, but none of them had this feature. The reason I'd like to have this feature is I want to unplug the charger *before* the battery hits 100%. Or at the very least, know when I have hit 100%. I don't want to have the phone plugged any more than necessary since that will cause damage to the battery.

I read that the optimal range (for the battery in the long run) would be somewhere around 70% and 80%, i.e. you would try to keep the battery percentage in that interval at all times. It would be easier to maintain this if my phone sent me a notification whenever I reached one of the two points, as I can't use all my time checking the battery.

Does such an app exist?

EDIT: I don't have a MacBook. I'm looking for an app for iPhone.

Comment: I put my phone on to charge at night and it is at 100% in the morning. Not sure how long it has been at 100% for each morning but it seems fine for an iPhone 6s+ that I have used for about 3 years now...

Comment: https://medium.com/s/how-batteries-work/why-batteries-die-d8281e15f6c8

Source for the 70%-80% claim. 

I did the same for many years, but when I read this article, I stopped doing that. I have an even older iPhone than yours and I intend to use it as long as possible for environmental reasons. I also live in a place where cold winters really deteriorate battery durability.

Comment: Hmm, no mention of the various parts of charging cycles that tend to be a now standard part of the charging strategy for most, if not all, electronic devices - even Tesla which they do mention. A half-assed pseudo-scientific article IMHO...  And yes, I have cold winters too... 5 years for my car battery on average and it's not a small battery as it is diesel (I know fuel of Satan...)

Comment: I too have been charging my phone but in reverse to @Solar Mike. I charged my iPhone 6 every morning and unplugged it every night.  I have been doing this for years. I bought my iPhone 6 new,  The battery was replaced once due to the universal recall they had a few years ago.  This was not due to problems and was just a precautionary measure.  My iPhone worked fine for years.

Comment: A terminal command to get battery status is mentioned in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206866/237687 then make an applescript...

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [Coconut Battery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) that does this but it is hardwired for certain values all less than 50%.  There is also a setting for number of minutes left. Load the app and go to Preferences under the coconutBattery menu item. This opens a panel and one option is Notifications. See image below.

[image]

CoconutBattery is free but there is a Pro version for $9.99. This will also report on iOS devices connected to your computer.

Comment: Oh, this would've been great. I briefly skimmed the page and thought I could download it on my Windows PC, but yeah, can't. I edited the question to say I don't have a Mac.